# Examining SQLLite database contents when debugging a Xamarin Forms App

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

have an application and its writing to a SQLLite database. I can tell its writing by the application behaviour but want to examine the table contents just as I may do on a desktop application accessing a server. But the file is on the phone emulator - so how would I connect to this database to examine the contents.

Comment: for the Android emulator, use adb to extract the file.  For an iOS emulator, just access it via the file system.  There are numerous SQLite management GUI tools you can use.

Comment: Im wondering how do I find the file using adb

Comment: you have to specify the file path when you create the db in your app, so you should know where it is

Comment: Hi , not too much understanding your question . Have you solved it ? Having a look at this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLiteStudio to see all the data in the Sqlite database.

https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt